# what is limit of adding bcc mail id's for single mail

Tags: php, email, bcc

I am using my gmail hosting details for sending mail,

For sending single mail to multiple user I am adding there mail address into BCC

Now I just want to know the limit of adding BCC mail address.
Any idea?

Comment: limits depends on email service provider. for gmail it's 2000. check [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) for more detials.

Comment: @jagad89 yes its 2000, but if i add 5 mail address in cc or bcc for single mail and send it, gmail count's it as one mail. I wanted to know that how may comma separated mail id's I can add

Comment: show us your php code. nothing wrong at gmail service. something must be wrong in code.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my PHP script my client just wanted to know that if he can add 1000 mail id's in BCC

Comment: Ask him to try it should go out. Email might go to Spam